# How to get a non matching record in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Table1`

```
ID

001
002
001
001
001

...
```

I want to check the `id` from `table1` where id should be even. If `id` is different then i need to return `2` else `1`

How to write a query for this?

Comment: Do you want to find "even" Id's, or Id's with Even numbers of occurences ?

Comment: "Get non matching record in single row" How is your title related to your question at all?

Answer (score 2):

For `ID`s

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN [ID]%2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) 
FROM [table]
```

For `ID` `COUNT` :

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT([ID])%2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
 FROM [table] 
 GROUP BY [ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
 declare @t table (id varchar(50))

insert into @t values('001'),('001'),('002'),('002'),('001'),('002'),('002')

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN cast( [ID] as int) %2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END oddOrEven
FROM @t

--for counting
;with cte as
(
    SELECT [ID]%2 value,
        CASE cast( [ID] as int) %2 when 1 THEN count(1) else count(2) END  oddCount         
    FROM @t
        group by id
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, a `CASE` statement is not necessary here. I'm assuming you want to return `2` when `ID` is even, and `1` when `ID` is odd? As long as there aren't any non-digit characters in the values of the `ID` column, you can do the following:

```
SELECT [ID], 2 - CAST([ID] AS int) % 2
  FROM Table1
```

If you want to return `2` when `ID` is odd, and `1` when it is even (sorry, that wasn't clear from the question), then you can do this:

```
SELECT [ID], CAST([ID] AS int) % 2 + 1
  FROM Table1
```